# why I cannot set a function that return something on 'show.bs.modal'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 modals that will place the get_data on `modal-body` with different style and different condition when modal opened. But I have some issues when I create a function which return an ajax request. Here's my code:

```
var getFessap = function(event) {
     var fessap_id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');
     var url_get = $(event.relatedTarget).data('get');
     var data_get = { fessap_id: fessap_id };
     return $.get(url_get, data_get);
};

$('#Modal').on('show.bs.modal', getFessap.done(function(data){
     // action
}));

$('#otherModal').on('show.bs.modal', getFessap.done(function(data){
     // other action
}));
```

When I open console there's an error like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: getFessap.done is not a function

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getFessap` is a reference to your function. If you need to get its return value then you need to call (execute) it by adding `()`:

```
$('#Modal').on('show.bs.modal', getFessap().done(function(data){
     // action
}));
```

Having said that, it looks like you are using Twitter Bootstrap Modal box. It expect a reference to a function, so you need to do it like this:

```
$('#Modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    getFessap().done(function(data){
         // action
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was little bit more understand. But now the console show me the error **Cannot read property 'relatedTarget' of undefined**. :/

Comment: That's because you are not passing event to your function. What do you want to achieve? Maybe there is a better way to do it...